# style bootstrap multiselect to look like a normal select

Tags: css, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using bootstrap-multiselect to add dropdown multiselect functionaility to selects but I do not like the way it looks and can't seem to overide the style.

I would like it to look like a normal bootstrap form control but adding these classes does nothing.

```
<h1>Normal BS select</h1>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="select1">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
<h1>
Bootstrap multiselect
</h1>
<div class="input-group input-group-sm mb-2">
  <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="select2" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I have created a [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dawson8/qzdnkwos/14/) to show the difference.

I have also tried to change the bootstrap-multiselect stylesheet but again nothing I change seems to work

EDIT:- It is the grey background and lack of border of the bootstrap-multiselect that I do not like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap Multiselect is creating a button there which receives certain styles applied by classes like `.multiselect`. You can pretty easily override these in a way like the following:

```
button.multiselect {
  background-color: initial;
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
}
```

Here, I'm resetting the background color of the button generated by Multiselect by going to its initial value, but you can set it to `#ffffff;` or something else. The border style is copied from the Bootstrap default for the `.form-control` class.

If you're not familiar with debugging with Devtools, you can [start with Chrome's Devtools overview](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools), or look specifically for tutorials on how to use the devtools or inspector for your browser of choice.

Here it is applied to your fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/qzdnkwos/36/

You can tweak as needed.

Comment: Is it possible to have bootstrap select (drop down) to look like multiselect (combo box)?